# Ldapsearch through ssh tunell

Tags: ssh, tunnel, ldap, openldap

I have four machines A, B, C, D and I would like to use `ldapsearch` on the first machine through an ssh tunnel over to C with a jump from B to C. Currently `ldapsearch` on C contacts the ldap server on D, for example

```
someuser@remote-c $ ldapsearch -x -LLL 'uid=someuser'
...
This works and returns my info
...
```

On A I placed the correct certificate (copied the one I already had from C) and placed the following ldap config in `/etc/ldap.conf` (on `remote-c` this was inside `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`)

```
URI ldaps://localhost:5000
...
```

and run the following command (more or less, where I say `someuser` I mean the account I have on that machine)

```bash
someuser@remote-a $ ssh -L 5000:remote-d:636 -J someuser@remote-b someuser@remote-c
```

After some debugging I think that the tunnel is working but after openning the tunnel I still cannot contact the ldap server from `remote-a`.

The main problem is that it looks like ldapsearch is not really loading that config file even if it is mostly the same of the other machines.

**Versions.** I don't know maybe this depends on the OpenLDAP version I'm using so here they are:

- `remote-a`:

  ```bash
  someuser@remote-a $ ldapsearch -V
  ldapsearch: @(#) $OpenLDAP: ldapsearch 2.6.2 (May 29 2022 09:54:34) $
      openldap
      (LDAP library: OpenLDAP 20602)
  ```

  On this machine I can mostly install whatever I want so this is the most recent)
- `remote-c`:

  ```bash
  someuser@remote-c $ ~$ ldapsearch -V
  ldapsearch: @(#) $OpenLDAP: ldapsearch  (May  2 2020 00:44:42) $
      pbuilder@build01:/build/openldap-2.4.40+dfsg/debian/build/clients/tools
      (LDAP library: OpenLDAP 20440)
  ```

  This works but has an old ldap version I can't update.

So my question is if ldap actually expects the configuration in that place and if so if the string `ldaps://localhost:5000` is correct.

Comment: "placed the following ldap config in `/etc/ldap.conf` (on `remote-c` this was inside `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`)" – Yet the documentation states [different paths](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldap.conf#end). Have you read `man 5 ldap.conf` on `remote-a` and learned `/etc/ldap.conf` is the right path? (Or is there a symlink at the right path that ultimately points to `/etc/ldap.conf`?) If not, then place the config where the manual says it should be.

Comment: The manual on A sad to put the config inside `ETCDIR/ldap.conf` so I thought `/etc/ldap.conf` was the right place but it doesn't look like so. Now I tried `$HOME/.ldaprc` (another valid place from the man page) and now it seams to be reading the config but it still won't connect to the server